# How to handle exceptions in ExecuteAsync method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have wrapped the ExecuteAsync method of the Transient Fault Handling Application Block in a retry class as below:

```
public class RetryWrapper
{
    public Task IncrementalAsync(Func<Task> action)
    {
        var retryStrategy = new Incremental(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<AzureServiceBusDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);
        retryPolicy.Retrying += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Retry - Count = {0}, Delay = {1}, Exception = {2}",
            args.CurrentRetryCount, args.Delay, args.LastException.Message);
        };

        return retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(action);
    }
}
```

From my client function, I invoke it like below:

```
RetryWrapper retry = new RetryWrapper();
try
{
    retry.IncrementalAsync<bool>(this.SomeFunction);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("All retries failed. Exception details: {0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

And the SomeFunction definition is:

```
public async Task<bool> SomeFunction()
{
     await Task.Delay(100);
     throw new Exception("Incremental execute task generic");
}
```

When i run the program, it retries for three times but at the last attempt, does not throw the exception as it happens with ExecuteAction method:

```
Retry - Count = 1, Delay = 00:00:01, Exception = Incremental execute task generic
Retry - Count = 2, Delay = 00:00:03, Exception = Incremental execute task generic
Retry - Count = 3, Delay = 00:00:05, Exception = Incremental execute task generic
```

How do I catch the exceptions after all retries from the ExecuteAync method? Also, is it good to use wrapper class like this? Aim is to centralize the transient block code in one place so tomorrow I can switch the libraries. Please suggest if there is a better pattern.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675232.aspx) - _"**Important**: Recent versions of SDKs for both Azure Storage and Azure Service Bus natively support retries. It is recommended to use these instead of the Transient Fault Handling Application Block"_ [and also here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=pandp.50).aspx) _"The technology described [The Transient Fault Handling Application Block] is outdated and is no longer being maintained"_

Comment: We have legacy code interacting with SQL DB that needs retries too. Hence this approach to make it consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exception is available as part of the event arguments for the Retrying event handler I would guess that the retry policy itself is catching the exceptions. You probably can't get the exception directly in a try catch since the internal workings of the policy aren't rethrowing the exception.

You could however add some supporting properties to your `RetryWrapper` class.

```
public class RetryWrapper
{
    private const Int32 RetryTimes = 3;

    // Can be private if you don't need all available to caller.
    public IList<Exception> Exceptions { get; private set; }

    public Exception LastException => Exceptions.LastOrDefault() ?? null;

    public Boolean Failed => Exceptions.Count == _retryTimes;

    public RetryWrapper() {
        Exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    }

    public Task IncrementalAsync(Func<Task> action)
    {
        var retryStrategy = new Incremental(RetryTimes, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        var retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<AzureServiceBusDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);

        retryPolicy.Retrying += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Retry - Count = {0}, Delay = {1}, Exception = {2}",
            args.CurrentRetryCount, args.Delay, args.LastException.Message);
            Exceptions.Add(args.LastException);
        };

        return retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(action);
    }
}
```

Then

```
RetryWrapper retry = new RetryWrapper();
retry.IncrementalAsync<bool>(this.SomeFunction);
if (retry.Failed) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("All retries failed. Exception details: {0}", retry.LastException.Message.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Your approach works. I worked around in another way. I marked the _IncrementalAsync_ method _async_ _**"public async Task IncrementalAsync(Func<Task> action)"_** and then await on the return statement inside this function _**"await return retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(action)"**_. This returns the last exception too.

Comment: @vmn Please mark the answer as Accepted if it helped. Thanks!